# NetBeans 64bit Edition

Tags: netbeans, 32bit-64bit

Does NetBeans have 64bit edition for Windows 64bit or NetBeans only published in 32bit edition?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, apparently it does.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqInstall64Bit

As mentioned in a comment, there is really no difference between the two versions; the difference lies in which flavor JDK you point it at.

Hope this helps,
Christian Stewart

Comment: Note that it looks like you need a 64-bit JVM as well.

Comment: of course, but there is one download link in Netbeans website for Windows OS! My Question is, does netbeans have two setup edition for Win32bit and Win64bit?

Comment: You should mention that the download for 64 and 32 bit versions of the IDE is the same, the difference lies in which Java Runtime Environment the install is pointed to. You have to point it to the 64 bit JRE to have it work in 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

It only depends on 36/64 bit version of JDK. If you have 64bit JDK, then Netbeans will run as 64bit. Generally there is no difference between 32/64 Netbeans but there is HUGE difference in memory consuming. In 64bit mode Netbeans will consume about twice memory of 32bit. I'm using 64bit at work on 4GB machine and NB takes about 500MB right after startup then hour later there is 800-900MB taken (which is horrifying - this is just advanced text editor). On my home 8GB machine I have 32bit version and Netbeans consume about 300MB. I'm using version 7.3.1